# Wrong template url when build in production (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript

This is how I defined my component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'LoginForm',
 templateUrl: "./" + (window.screen.width > 900 ?
 'login.component.html' :
 'login.component.mobile.html'),
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
```

This work when I'm using it in dev mode.
If I build with :

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

This doesn't work anymore.
Am I doing something wrong? (probably)
If so how can I fix this?

I'm using angular 4.

Comment: You get any error i mean you get error on build?

Comment: try write: declare window:any; at first of your component

Comment: @bipinpatel I got no error when building

Comment: @Eliseo it didn't worked, but maybe I'm doing something wrong, could you please write how I should write it?

Comment: added your error